# Plotting in Matlab with datetime in X axis

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot

I am trying to plot a graph with temperature values(Y) vs. datetime(X).
The datetime is constituted of many equal dates, without hour associated. For example, I would have 1440 values with 2018/01/11, then other 1440 values with 2018/01/12.., whereas for each point I have a different temperature value.
This is what it should look like:
[image]

But this is how it ended up when I use plot(temperature, date):
[image]

All the values for the same day are accumulated as it was a stem ..
I would need it to map point 1 of Y with point 1 of X, and so on, without recognizing the X axis as a datetime, but instead to recognize it as a string. I don't know if I am explaining it right.

But to give a simple example, basically would be something like:
Y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
X = [2016, 2016, 2016, 2016]
And all the 2016 should be different sequence values on the graph.

Would someone be able to help me, please?

Comment: If you provide a sample of your code to plot. Is the data sampled at constant rate or does the increment in time from one sample to the next change? Looks like your first figure is the data plotted against its the index (ie: `X=1:length(Y)` or just `plot(Y)`).

Comment: Hello @AzimJ! Yes, the first one it is simply plotted with a plot(Y), and the second is a plot(X,Y). It is not a constante sampling rate, but both sets (values and date) have the same size.

Comment: If sample rate isn't constant that could explain the gaps you see in the second plot. Since the first plot assumes a constant sample rate, you won't pick up these gaps which may exist in due to non-constant sampling rate. I would suggest plotting data around the gap just before July 2018. You might have a gap in samples that doesn't show up in the first plot. Does that make sense?